# TCP Library is bundling messages?

Tags: c++, api, tcp

I'm using a TCP library with a Server and Client class called Lacewing http://lacewing-project.org/

I have noticed that when I send a client several separate messages, it sometimes bundles them and the only way I can separate them is by parsing them again. When sending binary data, it is very hard to parse though.

Does anyone know why it might do this? I tried the DisableNagling() on both client and server but it still does it.

Here is an example of something I might send:

```
void ServerCore::loginRequestC( const std::string& userName, const std::string& password )
{
    std::cout << "Got request" << std::endl;
    ServerPlayer* player = (ServerPlayer*)getServerClient()->Tag;
    player->setUsername(userName);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_players.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(m_players[i] != player)
        {
            std::cout << "Telling new about " << m_players[i]->getUsername() << std::endl;
            m_enc.playerJoinedS(m_players[i]->getUsername());
            player->getClient()->Send(m_enc.getLastMessage().c_str());
        }
    }

    m_enc.loginResultS(true,"");

    player->getClient()->Send(m_enc.getLastMessage().c_str());

    m_enc.playerJoinedS(userName);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_players.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(m_players[i] != player)
        m_players[i]->getClient()->Send(m_enc.getLastMessage().c_str());
    }

}
```

So if I intended to have:

```
MSG_A
MSG_B
MSG_C
```

It might send:

```
MSG_A
MSG_BMSG_C
```

The messages get randomly bundled together. It is not my code that is the problem. I have checked.

Although it is useful to bundle messages, I want to control when it happens, not the library.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not the library, but the TCP protocol itself that is doing it. TCP socket is a bi-directional *stream of bytes*. One write might result in multiple reads on the other side, and vise versa.

You have to design you *application-level protocol* so that it's easy to split that stream into messages. Common approaches are to use a length prefix or a message delimiter.

Comment: Would I only ever get part of a message, example MS then the next be G_B

Comment: Yes, you need to read bytes in in a loop until you have enough bytes to figure out what/where the message is.

Answer (score 2):

TCP is stream oriented protocol, thus it has no build in message boundaries. You will need to split the stream to messages by yourself.

UDP in opposite is datagram protocol and each packet has a separate message. A disadvantage is that it's not reliable.